# How to add a Chart after a Sheet by PyWin32?

Tags: python, excel, charts, pywin32

Let us suppose that I create a new chart by

```
chart = excel.Charts.Add()
```

where

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

I want that such a chart be added AFTER another sheet, for example, ws. I tried

```
chart = excel.Charts.Add(After=ws)
```

but it does not work. Any idea how to do it? How can I get the Sheet object where chart is located?

Answer (score 2):

Try this configuration:

You have a book with sheets, you create one more sheet type chart, with the type you get from this link: [XlSheetType enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcharttype)

Then you add it after the sheet you need.

You can choose the chart type from this link: [eXlChartType enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsheettype)

For the example, it is a chart type sheet, 3DPie chart.

For the position of the legend see this link: [XlLegendPosition enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllegendposition)

```
import win32com.client as client

excel = client.Dispatch("excel.application") # Excel Object
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("path/excel_name.xlsx") # Book Object
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet_Name") # Sheet Object

workchart = workbook.Sheets.Add(After=worksheet, Type=-4109) # New Chart Object
workchart.Name = "Chart_Name" # Chart Sheet Name
workchart.ChartType = -4102 # 3DPie
workchart.HasTitle = True

workchart_title = workchart.ChartTitle
workchart_title.Text = "Chart_Title"
# workchart_title_font = workchart_title.Font
# workchart_title_font.ColorIndex = 0 # Black Color
# workchart_title_font.Bold = True

workchart.HasLegend = True
workchart.Legend.Position = -4152 # Right Position

workbook.SaveAs("path/excel_with_chart.xlsx")
workbook.Close(False); workbook=None
excel.Application.Quit()
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)[charts](/questions/tagged/charts)[pywin32](/questions/tagged/pywin32)